# Trouble with connection to openVPN

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I have openVPN on my VPS and connect to it from 2 computers(at home, at work) with ubuntu onboard. Now I can't connect to my vpn at work, I guess that some changes in corporate network, maybe cause it, how to find problem?

show it:

```
Jun  4 15:03:11 u200 NetworkManager[906]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Jun  4 15:03:11 u200 NetworkManager[906]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started     (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 3585
Jun  4 15:03:11 u200 NetworkManager[906]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Jun  4 15:03:11 u200 NetworkManager[906]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: init (1)
Jun  4 15:03:11 u200 NetworkManager[906]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Jun  4 15:03:11 u200 NetworkManager[906]: <info> VPN connection 'VPN *****' (Connect) reply received.
Jun  4 15:03:11 u200 nm-openvpn[3588]: OpenVPN 2.2.1 i686-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Feb 27 2013
Jun  4 15:03:11 u200 nm-openvpn[3588]: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Jun  4 15:03:11 u200 nm-openvpn[3588]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Jun  4 15:03:11 u200 nm-openvpn[3588]: WARNING: file '/home/******.key' is group or others accessible
Jun  4 15:03:11 u200 nm-openvpn[3588]: LZO compression initialized
Jun  4 15:03:11 u200 nm-openvpn[3588]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Jun  4 15:03:11 u200 nm-openvpn[3588]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]**********:1194
Jun  4 15:03:51 u200 NetworkManager[906]: <warn> VPN connection 'VPN *****' (IP Config Get) timeout exceeded.
Jun  4 15:03:51 u200 nm-openvpn[3588]: SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
Jun  4 15:03:51 u200 NetworkManager[906]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Jun  4 15:03:56 u200 NetworkManager[906]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
Jun  4 15:05:01 u200 CRON[3663]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection is timing out while it is establishing

```
Jun  4 15:03:51 u200 NetworkManager[906]: <warn> VPN connection 'VPN *****' (IP Config Get) timeout exceeded.
```

OpenVPN asked a question and waited so long for a response that a failsafe kicked in (timeout).  You know that OpneVPN works because you can use it at home

It is likely work is blocking ports used (your VPN connection would need to be configured to use a different port) or they are using a deep inspection firewall which has been told to prevent VPN connections (which you can not fix unless you know a LOT about hiding traffic).

OpenVPN uses TCP 1194 and UDP 443.  My guess is that TCP port 1194 has been blocked.  Try going to a secure website (amazon.com as an example).  If https:// comes up in the browser and works, port 443 is likely working (has to be for SSL to work).  This narrows the likely problem to the port number (1194), or UDP being filtered.

Try creating an FTP connection from work to an address on the internet.  If that works it is likely that all UDP traffic is NOT filtered, and that you are looking at a port number problem.  If you can change the configuration of OpenVPN on your VPS to work with a different port (8080 may look like web traffic to a firewall at work), then this MAY remedy the problem.

Comment: set 443 port and tcp connection, it solved my problem!